# use link to add content to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is the simplest way to use a link to populate a input text box with the link content?

I have these links - quite few like these

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Add Code to quick Quote Form">P3030-6</a>
<a href="javascript:;" title="Add Code to quick Quote Form">P3030-6</a>
```

this text box

```
<input type="text" name="code" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text sidebarInput" id="code" aria-invalid="false">
```

When someone clicks on the link I want the P3030-6 etc to be added to the text box.

I have a great little script that uses jquery 1.7, but my site needed 1.10.2 - and adding the 1.7 scrip stopped some of the funcitonality of the site.

Any ideas on the best process greatly received!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could add a class on the links

```
<a href="" class="forinput" title="Add Code to quick Quote Form">P3030-6</a>
```

then something like

```
$('.forinput').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#code').val($(this).text());
});
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uv5Gx/)

EDIT

to add

```
$('.forinput').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $code = $('code');
    $code.val($code.val() + $(this).text());
});
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uv5Gx/2/)

Comment: Yes - that one works for me.......how do add to the content rather than replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
href="" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=this.innerHTML;return false;"
```

That should be in each link.  Or you can do it systemically through Javascript but someone did that already so I'm gonna be different and lame.

```
onclick="var code = document.getElementById('code');code.value=(code.value.indexOf(this.innerHTML) < 0) ? code.value + ', ' + this.innerHTML : code.value;return false;"
```

Comment: This appears to be the best option for my website, I have managed to get ot to append additional items as below - is it possible to avoid dupications :          <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=this.innerHTML + ', ' + document.getElementById('code').value ;return false;" title="Add Code to quick Quote Form">P3030-6</a>

Comment: Yes this can be accomplished with the code I just added to my post.  It will add a comma and then the link text if it's not already there and if it's there, it doesn't add anything.

Comment: @user1088207 :  you should learn basic of jquery. you should ask here specific question. you have any idea what is jquery? i do not think so. put some efforts from your end if you face any specefic issue then ask in SO.

Comment: No - else I would not have posted a question on a forum asking for help......I am a php programmer and not had time to look at jquery properly yet....if you did not want to help - why reply?

Comment: @user1088207 I don't know why he replied to my answer but look at my edit and you have what you asked for.  You don't need jQuery here if you really don't want it.

Comment: hmmm some people must have nothing better to do.....perfect - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it may ways. it depends on your anchor tag position. you can get anchor tag by its parents elements. (e.g i have used a div with class content as parent).

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/597/

```
<div class="content">
  <a href="javascript:;" title="Add Code to quick Quote Form">P3030-61</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" title="Add Code to quick Quote Form">P3030-62</a>

   <input type="text" name="code" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text sidebarInput" id="code" aria-invalid="false">

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".content a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#code').val($(this).text());
     console.log("fddsf");
    })
```

If you want to add all anchor clicked text:
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/598/
then replace

```
$('#code').val($(this).text());
```

by

```
$('#code').val($('#code').val()+$(this).text());
```

if you don't want duplicate values :

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/600/

```
$(".content a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    var out = $('#code').val();
    if(out.indexOf($(this).text()) == -1) {
      $('#code').val(out+$(this).text());
    }
  })
```

you can add `,` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/607/

```
$(".content a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var out = $('#code').val();
if(out.indexOf($(this).text()) == -1) {
    out = out == '' ? out: out+',';
  $('#code').val(out+$(this).text());
}
```

})

Comment: That works well - is there a way of adding to the text rather then replacing it?

Comment: do you mean appending?

Comment: yes so if they click more than one they will all be added to the text box ie P3030-61, P3030-62

Comment: Sorry about this....works prefect on jsfiddle, but not on my website. the only options that works on the website its self is adding href="" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=this.innerHTML;return false;" to al the links.....